# JavaScript or HTML launching a new browser from hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-intent, web

So, I'm working on an app which is a web based app. The apps code base is mostly written in JavaScript and HTML. The app is also available on a native app which basically only contains a `WebView` displaying the HTML and JavaScript code.

My problem is that when a user is on the Android native version and launching an external link, it opens perfectly in the Android `WebView` but there is some cases where the launched page not is scrollable and other strange stuff.

So to solve this issue I need the native app to launch the in-build browser in the Android phone. Basically, the exact same effect that `startActivity(new Intent(ACTION.VIEW,URI))` has. 
The thing is that I can't modify the Android version though all the logic is written within the web app..

### My question is:

Is there any way to simulate:

```
startActivity(new Intent(ACTION.VIEW,URI))
```

in JavaScript to get out of the native app and launch the browser instead?

Comment: try this..https://github.com/mohit008/Android-Web-view/blob/master/src/com/example/view/MainActivity.java

Comment: Not sure if I missunderstood, but you want something like this: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser